# Headphone jack doesn't work in Windows 7 since installing Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, 64-bit, headphones

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit fine with a CD on a different partition. The speakers and headphones work fine in Ubuntu, but only the speakers work in Windows 7. The microphone works fine in both, the only thing I can think of is it could be something with Ubuntu? I am fairly new to using Ubuntu, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will help, but my personal experience is that it is all on windows. Check and make sure you don't have a disabled device in your sound options.

Follow instructions here to see how: http://clc.its.psu.edu/labs/windows/help/sound-is-disabled

Hope this helps!